# couchbase sort issue in java code

Tags: couchbase

Below is the document on which I am working:

```
{
   "id": "idgwSRWDUJjQH",
   "rev": "15-13d1d4545cd601560000000000000000",
   "expiration": 0,
   "flags": 0
}
    {
   "geminiType": "storegroup",
   "_class": "web.model.StoreGroup",
   "order": "10",
   "childId": [
   ],
   "name": "aaa",
   "parent": "root",
   "userGroupId": [
   ],
   "type": "Folder",
   "storeId": [
   ]
}
```

I am trying to sort based on name as below

```
function (doc, meta) {
 if(doc.geminiType == "storegroup") {
  emit(doc.name, [ meta.id,doc.name, doc.parent, doc.type]);
}
}
```

This I have created permanent view in couchbase console. I am fetching the document from my jave code using couchbase client as below:

```
View storeGrpView = cc.getView(RRConsts.STORE_GROUP_VIEW_DESIGN_DOC, RRConsts.STORE_GROUP_VIEW);        

        Query getAllstoreGrpQuery = new Query();
        getAllstoreGrpQuery.setIncludeDocs(true);
        getAllstoreGrpQuery.setStale(Stale.FALSE);
        ViewResponse result = cc.query(storeGrpView, getAllstoreGrpQuery);
        logger.info("getAllstoreGrpQuery resultset: " + result.toString());

        for(ViewRow row : result) {
            logger.info("store group :"+row.getDocument().toString());
                }
        }
```

Here I am getting the result in order of meta.id of the doc but i was expecting the result set to be in order of doc.name. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to above issue. Actually if I used below two get method instead of row.getDocument() to fetch data, I am getting data in sorted order as expected.

row.getkey()
row.getvalue()